# Show and hide forms with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to insert value in database through ajax. There rows which are coming in while loop from database. I have added one column in each row which have button. On click of button i am submitting the values in database its working fine. Delete query is also working fine.

I want to hide select form on successful submission and show cancel form.

And when insert query fails want to display error.

Then display select form when delete query is successful on click Cancel button.

Need help. Thanks in advance

PHP Code :

While loop Code :

```
if($num_rowsslctcncl)
{
    $slctcncldis="<form name='cancel_selection' class='cancel_selection' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$coursename'>
    <input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>

    <button class='btn btn-cancel btn-xs' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </form>";
}

if(!$num_rowsslctcncl)
{
    $slctcncldis="<form name='form_submit_change_status' class='form_submit_change_status' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$coursename'>
    <input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>

    <button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' value='Select Course'>Select Course</button>
    </form>";
}

echo"<tbody><tr>
<td>$crs</td>
<td>$slctcncldis </td>
```

Ajax and javascript Code :

Insert Function Code :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-warning').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest(".form_submit_change_status");
        var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
        var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();
        var URL = "response.php";

        $.post(URL, formData).done(function(data) {
        });

        fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(errorThrown);  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Delete function code :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-cancel').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest(".cancel_selection");
        var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
        var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();

        var URL = "cancelselection.php";
        $.post(URL, formData)
        .done(function(data) {
        });

        fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Response.php

Insert query code:

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");

    $crs = $_POST["crs"];
    $sid = $_POST["insertid"]; 

    $strscheck="SELECT * FROM add_delete_record where sid='$sid'";
    $resultscheck=mysql_query($strscheck) or die(mysql_error());

    $num_rowscheck = mysql_num_rows($resultscheck);

    if($num_rowscheck < 3)
    {
        $strsreg="insert into add_delete_record  (sno, chcourse, sid) values('', '$crs','$sid')";
        $resultsreg=mysql_query($strsreg) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
    }
?>
```

Comment: I am not getting any answer on my question. Am i asking wrong questions?

Comment: The thing is nobody wants to read so much code. Try to post relevant code and keep it short and simple to explain what your problem is.

Comment: but when i give short code, everyone asks for full code.. Can u plz help me on this. Stuck on this from so many hours

Comment: @Test added the answer below. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print both forms in loop. Instead of inserting selected form, show and hide the form initially. Try something like this. Compare it with your code you will find the difference.

```
if($num_rowsslctcncl)
{
    $slctcncldis_Cancel ="<form name='cancel_selection' class='cancel_selection' style="display:block;" action=''>
            <input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$coursename'>
            <input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>
            <button class='btn btn-cancel btn-xs' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
        </form>";

} else {
    $slctcncldis_Cancel ="<form name='cancel_selection' class='cancel_selection' style="display:none;" action=''>
            <input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$coursename'>
            <input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>
            <button class='btn btn-cancel btn-xs' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
        </form>";
}

if(!$num_rowsslctcncl)
{

    $slctcncldis_Submit ="<form name='form_submit_change_status' class='form_submit_change_status' style="display:block;" action=''>
            <input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$coursename'>
            <input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>
            <button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' value='Select Course'>Select Course</button>
            </form>";

} else {
    $slctcncldis_Submit ="<form name='form_submit_change_status' class='form_submit_change_status' style="display:none;" action=''>
            <input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$coursename'>
            <input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>
            <button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' value='Select Course'>Select Course</button>
            </form>";

}

echo"<tbody><tr>
<td>$crs</td>
<td>$slctcncldis_Cancel.$slctcncldis_Submit</td>    


    Ajax and javascript Code :

Insert Function Code :

    <script>
$(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-warning').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest(".form_submit_change_status");

    var $cancel_form = $form.siblings(".cancel_selection");

        var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
        var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();


        var URL = "response.php";
        $.post(URL, formData).done(function(data) {
        $form.hide();
        $cancel_form.show();
        });

        fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(errorThrown);  
        });


    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Kuldeep it helps to some extent. But initially it shows both form. that i dont want to do because it allows to select selected item again. Can we done through response.php where insert query is working when it successful then hide select form and show cancel form

Comment: It should not show both forms, check style="display:none;" and style="display:block;" for both forms in my answer. You should apply these styles before printing the forms.

Comment: Kuldeep yes its woking fine now. Thank u so much. Need to do one more thing from response.php  if($num_rowscheck > 3) I want to show some msg

Comment: one problem is there if insert query not successful it still change button from select to cancel

Comment: You need to modify your "$.post(URL, formData).done(function(data) {}" function. Read the 'data' which is coming from server, if it contains error then do not show/hide forms. If 'data' contains success message then show/hide forms

Comment: You need to modify your server side php (response.php) file for this. Check if insertion is successful echo "OK" else "FAILED". Then you can read these messages in 'data'

Comment: How it can be done can u plz advise. and Need to do one more thing from response.php if($num_rowscheck > 3) I want to show some msg

Comment: As I mentioned, use echo "<your_message>" in response.php. This message can be anything a simple text, json, underscore separated values. After this just console.log(data) in you ".done" function you will find server message in data object

Comment: No its not working. can u plz edit in your answer how it can be done and in response.php file also. It would be great help for me

Comment: Kuldeep waiting for your reply

Comment: hi Kuldeep Can u plz help me out with one more question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342870/if-validation-successful-hide-submit-button-and-show-loading-image/43343496#43343496