# if validation successful hide submit button and show loading image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form to submit data in to a database through mysql php. I am using validation to check if the fields have values or not. Now I want if validation successful on submit button, hide the submit button and show loading image till the time user do not go to submission successful page.

Validation code is working fine. But problem is in hiding submit and showing loading image.

Validation Code :

```
    $('.msf-form form').on('submit', function(e){ 
    $(".loading").show();

    $(".sbmt").hide();
    var return_val = true;
    console.log('test');

    $(this).find('.is_mobile:visible').each(function() {                                       
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            return_val = false;
            $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
            $(".error-messages-mobile").text("Your valid Mobile Number is required ").fadeIn();
        }
        else{
           $(this).css('border','0px solid #F44336');
           $(".error-messages-mobile").empty().fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $(this).find('.is_otp:visible').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            return_val = false;
            $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
            $(".error-messages-otp").text("OTP is required ").fadeIn();
        }
        console.log(return_val);

        if(return_val == true){
            return_val = false;
            var data = {
                countryCode: $('#hiddenCode').val(),
                mobileNumber: $('#hiddenNumber').val(),
                oneTimePassword: $('#oneTimePassword').val()
              };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.com',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {console.log(response);
                  if (response == 'NUMBER VERIFIED SUCCESSFULLY') {
                        $(".error-messages-votp").empty().fadeOut();
                        $('.msf-form form').unbind('submit');
                        $('.msf-form form').submit();

                        return true;

                  }
                  else
                  {
                        return_val = false;
                        $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
                        $(".error-messages-otp").text("Enter valid OTP ").fadeIn();
                  }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, ex) { return_val = false;
                  console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    }); 

    if(!return_val){
        $(".loading").hide();
        $(".sbmt").show(); 
        return return_val;
    } 
});
```

Style for loading div :

Code :

```
<style>
    .loading{
  display:none;
  color:#FF0000;
}
</style>
```

Html and PHP Form Code:

I have two inputs mobile number and OTP. I want if two of them have values then hide submit button on click and show loading image.

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Enter Mobile number" id="number" class="is_mobile" ><br />

<input type="hidden" name="country_code" id="country_code" class="is_vcountrycode" value="91" ><br>

<span class="error-messages-mobile" id="error"></span><br>

<div id="verifyOtpForm" >

    <input type="text" name="oneTimePassword" placeholder="Enter OTP" id="oneTimePassword" class="is_otp"><br><br>
    <span class="error-messages-otp" id="error"></span><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenCode" id="hiddenCode">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenNumber" id="hiddenNumber"><br>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn sbmt">Submit</button>
<div class="loading" style="font-size:22px;"><img src="images/loading1.gif"></div>
```

Comment: You could have the button change on submit to that image, so perhaps use .hide in jQuery and then .show on the image. I.e. you would need to create the div to be identical to the submit button right below but with display:none

Comment: @LewisSmith I have done this already you can check this in my question. But not working

Comment: Sorry misread, okay so I have had this problem before, try making a new function with everything you want it to do on success. Then trigger that on success. Shouldn't need to but that should do the trick

Comment: Also you should be using === rather than == might help

Comment: @LewisSmith I am not geting properly what you are saying can u plz explain with code.

Comment: can anyone give solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

what is output in console? - console.log(response);

Comment: It does not hide submit button and submit the value in database and go to next page. Problem is not the validation. It is validating. but not hiding submit button on validation success

Comment: Use comment if you have any query. Don't use answer section to ask something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
if(!return_val){
    $(".loading").hide();
    $(".sbmt").show(); 
    return return_val;
}
```

Code in AJAX success and error function.

This code gets executed before AJAX call respond. So try putting it in success and error block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make following changes

**1. Change**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn sbmt">Submit</button>
```

To

```
<button type="button" class="btn sbmt">Submit</button>
```

**2. Change**

```
$('.msf-form form').on('submit', function(e){
```

To

```
$('.msf-form form').on('click', function(e){
```

**3. Remove**

```
if(!return_val) {
      $(".loading").hide();
      $(".sbmt").show(); 
      return return_val;
    }
```

**4. Change your Ajax else condition**

From

```
else {
  return_val = false;
  $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
  $(".error-messages-otp").text("Enter valid OTP ").fadeIn();
}
```

to

```
else {
  return_val = false;
  $(".loading").hide();
  $(".sbmt").show(); 
  $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
  $(".error-messages-otp").text("Enter valid OTP ").fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: @kuldeeep Singh Thanks for your answer and support. I have one equestion If I hide submit button on ajax else then It can not validate name textbox has value or not then it will hide submit button on validation of OTP. Plz advise. I have textbox of enter name and i am also validating it.

Comment: No we are not hiding the submit button on ajax else. If you see, we are enabling the form button in else condition.

Comment: Your existing condition to show submit won't work as ajax is async call. Your condition will be executed before ajax call response, so it won't show the loading image.

Comment: But now it hide submit button before validating and show loading image

Comment: Do you want to hide submit button if ajax validation fails?

Comment: No I do not want to hide submit button on ajax fails but its hiding submit button if there are empty fields

Comment: ok remove $(".sbmt").hide(); from top and add it just before ajax call

Comment: Hi Kuldeep Can u Plz help me out on this topic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650270/use-gallery-shortocode-on-another-page-but-with-specific-photo-category-in-wordp/43650310?noredirect=1#comment74348598_43650310