# Use Gallery Shortocode on another page but with specific photo category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, shortcode

I have a galley page in a wordpress theme. Now I want to use that gallery shortcode on some other pages but want to display photos only from specfic photo category. Thanks in advance.

Following is gallery short code:

```
[gallery_list]
```

Following is photo category ID which I Want to use in this short code :

```
cat&tag_ID=50
```

Answer (score 0):

If the gallery supports Id parameters, you'd do something like this:

`[gallery_list tag_ID="50" cat="XX"]`

[Wordpress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Hi can u Plz confirm what is cat=="XX" and where to check if the gallery supports id parameters or not

Comment: cat="XX" is an example of how you'd pass the categoryId into the gallery. You may check your theme/plugin gallery documentation in order to check if is parameters are supported

Comment: I am not able to find where to check id parameters